# Iterating array of objects and joining the key values with commas

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have an array of objects containing addresses like this:

```
let addressArray = [
  {
    street: '123 Charm St',
    city: 'Tuscaloosa',
    state: 'AL'
  },
  {
    street: '456 Hampton Ave',
    city: 'Tuscaloosa',
    state: 'AL'
  },
  {
    street: '789 Greenview Dr',
    city: 'Austin',
    state: 'TX'
  }
]
```

I want to join each the key values into a single string with comma delimeters like this:

```
streets = '123 Charm St,456 Hampton Ave,789 Greenview Dr'
cities = 'Tuscaloosa,Tuscaloosa,Austin'
states = 'AL,AL,TX'
```

Currently I map three times (once for each key) and join each value by comma like this:

```
const streets = addressArray.map((elem) => elem.street).join(",");
const cities = addressArray.map((elem) => elem.city).join(",");
const states = addressArray.map((elem) => elem.state).join(",");
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this? So I don't have 3 repetitive map calls?

Note: If there are empty values, it should still separate the empty value with comma, for example:

```
let addressArray = [
  {
    street: '',
    city: 'Tuscaloosa',
    state: 'AL'
  },
  {
    street: '456 Hampton Ave',
    city: 'Tuscaloosa',
    state: 'AL'
  },
  {
    street: '789 Greenview Dr',
    city: 'Austin',
    state: 'TX'
  }
]
```

The `streets` string for the above array should be `,456 Hampton Ave,789 Greenview Dr`

Comment: `The streets string for the above array should be ,456 Hampton Ave,789 Greenview Dr` so ... is it? I can't think of a more concise way to achieve what you want

Comment: the only issue I can see is that `streets` will be `,,` for the obvious reason (typo in the question?)

Comment: No these strings are going to be used in a request so the commas are important in establishing order between the fields. So if we had two empty street values it would be `,,789 Greenview Dr`

Comment: "*Is there a more concise way of doing this? So I don't have 3 repetitive map calls?*" create a function that takes parameters. Call the function three times.

Comment: Yep I thought of this but I was wondering if there was a more concise couple liners..

Comment: You'd still be *repeating* the code, even if it's shorter. If you want a *good* solution, then don't repeat the code.

Comment: Yes I was wondering if there was a better way to not repeat code but still get the strings I want?

Comment: Yes - create a function that generalises the code you already have. Then you'll have a single copy of the code. And the function will be about a line long.

Comment: You could contatenate the strings and use a delimeter at the join points

`joined = "str1 | str2 | str3".split("|")` And you can do map. But this would mean you have to write a lot of code for a very simple problem, though.

Comment: Your code still won't produce what you say it will, no idea why you went on about establishing order blah blah, your code will always result in `streets` being `",,"` .. because you are doing something wrong with `streets` (the other two are fine) - hint: none of your objects have a property `address`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Array#reduce` and store the concatenated string for each key in an object to avoid repeating the logic.

```js
let addressArray=[{street:"123 Charm St",city:"Tuscaloosa",state:"AL"},{street:"456 Hampton Ave",city:"Tuscaloosa",state:"AL"},{street:"789 Greenview Dr",city:"Austin",state:"TX"}];
const { streets, citys: cities, states } = addressArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  Object.entries(curr).forEach(([k, v]) => 
    Object.hasOwn(acc, k + 's') ? acc[k + 's'] += ',' + v : acc[k + 's'] = v);
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(streets);
console.log(cities);
console.log(states);
```

Comment: You'd have to agree that is not more concise :p (I was going to suggest similar, I like how you handle the pluralisation though)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

1. Reduce address parts into value groups (arrays of property values).
   (See custom function `groupByProperties()` below.)
2. Join values of groups.
3. Assign joined values to `streets`, `cities`, `states` via [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Defining `groupByProperties()` is for both readability and reusability. When using it, your issue (grouping, joining and assigning) could neatly fit into one line.

```js
const addressArray = [
  {street: '123 Charm St', city: 'Tuscaloosa', state: 'AL'},
  {street: '456 Hampton Ave', city: 'Tuscaloosa', state: 'AL'},
  {street: '789 Greenview Dr', city: 'Austin', state: 'TX'}
];

const [streets, cities, states] =
  groupByProperties(["street", "city", "state"], addressArray)
    .map(values => values.join(","));

console.log(streets);
console.log(cities);
console.log(states);

/**
 * Returns the objects' properties as groups of values.
 * @param {Array<String>} props the properties to group
 * @param {Array<any>} objects the objects to group values from
 * @returns {Array<Array<unknown>>} an array of grouped values, ordered as given by `props`
 */
function groupByProperties(props, objects) {
  return props.reduce((groups, prop, i) => {
    groups[i] = [];
    objects.forEach(obj => groups[i].push(obj[prop]));
    return groups;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reduce, all you need to do is create a dimensional array.

```js
const groupByProperties = (props, ...objects) =>
  props.map(prop => objects.map(obj => obj[prop]));

const addresses = [
  { street: '123 Charm St'     , city: 'Tuscaloosa' , state: 'AL' },
  { street: '456 Hampton Ave'  , city: 'Tuscaloosa' , state: 'AL' },
  { street: '789 Greenview Dr' , city: 'Austin'     , state: 'TX' }
];

const [streets, cities, states] =
  groupByProperties(['street', 'city', 'state'], ...addresses)
    .map(values => values.join(","));

console.log({ streets, cities, states });
```

Answer (score 0):

`_.mergeWith` might come in handy in this situation. It goes through each key, and you can specify how you want to combine them.

```js
const addressArray = [
  { street: "123 Charm St", city: "Tuscaloosa", state: "AL" },
  { street: "456 Hampton Ave", city: "Tuscaloosa", state: "AL" },
  { street: "789 Greenview Dr", city: "Austin", state: "TX" }
];

function customizer(resultValue, sourceValue) {
  return resultValue.concat(sourceValue);
}

let result = { street: [], city: [], state: [] }

_.mergeWith(result, ...addressArray, customizer)

console.log(result.street.join(','))
console.log(result.city.join(','))
console.log(result.state.join(','))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```